Linear algebra problem about $n$ miners sitting at a table
There are $n$ miners sitting at a table, each of whom has a pile of gold sand in front of them. Every minute the following happens: on a general command, each of them puts half of the sand from the pile of the left neighbor and half from the pile of the right neighbor. Describe the asymptotic behavior
heaps (a) for $n = 3$; (b) for arbitrary $n$.
The first part of the problem seems clear. In fact we have to deal with the following equation:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{n} \\
    y_{n} \\
    z_{n} 
\end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0.5  & 0.5 \\
    0.5 & 0 & 0.5\\
    0.5 & 0.5  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{n-1} \\
    y_{n-1} \\
    z_{n-1} 
\end{bmatrix}
$
I diagonalized matrix, then found its $n$-th degree and got the solution : every miner is going to have $\frac{(x_0 + y_0 + z_0)}{3}$ amount of gold sand.
What  to do in  general case? I  don't  understand how to find eigenvalues of matrix of order $n$ (it seems that they are complex)

See circulant matrix.

I assume this table is circular, or near enough, so that everybody has both a left and right neighbour?

@ChrisLewis  yes, you are right.

The description is confusing. Do you mean each of them takes half of the sand etc?

As mentioned before on another circulant matrices question,  if you have a guess for an eigenvector you can just show it works.  What is the generalization of the $n$-th degree solution you already found?
What happens when you put it through one round of the multiplication with matrix?  If it comes out a multiple of input, you know you have an eigenvector.
If you take an input with all zeroes except one miner what happens to the output?  Look at the levels of Pascal's triangle.  But then eventually get bigger than $n$ number of miners,  so it is Pascal's triangle modular number of miners. Wraps sum around.  Just a convolution at each stage,  so can use law of large numbers that converges to the average when modulus finite.
Actually I got this wrong.  What if have even number of people and start with only odd ones having gold?  Will go to average - but modula 2.  So will have long term average pile of gold,  but flips between odd and even miners. You mean in question they take half of pile from each neighbor each turn? So with even number of miners can have oscillating pattern between average of odd and average of even switching from odd and even places.
Another type of Matrix to look up is the Markov matrix. The eigenvector v to the eigenvalue 1 is called the stable equilibrium distribution ofA. It is also called Perron-Frobenius eigenvector.
